# store the local time of the client in mysql table

Tags: php

I am trying to store the local time zone of the client on the hosting home page ut I am getting this error in my android Logcat `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7` How can I do that? I tried it with `date_default_timezone_set`

I appreaciate any help.

```
<?php
 $data = json_decode ( file_get_contents ( 'php://input', true ) );


$mac = $data->{'mac'};
$latitude = $data->{'latitude'};
$longitude = $data->{'longitude'};
$route =   $data->{'route'};
$created_at = date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");


$con = new mysqli ( "domin.com", "username", "password", "ddatabase" );


// check whether route's table exist.
$results = $con->query ( "SHOW TABLES like 'bus' " ) or die ( mysqli_error () );

if (($results->num_rows) == 1) {$sql = "REPLACE INTO bus(mac, route, latitude, longitude, created_at)
          VALUES( ?, ?, ? , ?, ? )";
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

  if(false === $stmt){
    echo "prepare()  failed: ";
  }

  $rc = $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$mac,$route, $latitude,$longitude, $created_at );
 echo $rc;
  if ( false===$rc ) {
  echo "bind_param() failed: ";
}

  $rc = $stmt->execute();

  if ( false===$rc ) {
 echo "execute failed.";
  }

  $stmt->close();

} else {
  $create =  "CREATE TABLE bus
       (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        route int(11) ,
     latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL , 
     longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
     created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL" ;
   $stmt = $con->prepare($create) or die ( $con->error );
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) returns a bool, not a date. You can use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) without specifying a timestamp parameter to get the current client time. Make sure that the format of the date matches what your table expects.